# How does one use Hibernate Tools to create tables from POJOs?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-tools

I am having some trouble searching for what I want to do. I am told that I can generate database tables using Hibernate that represent POJOs I created in Java. I must be missing something. Thank you for the help on the trivial issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this property in your configuration file

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Comment: Then once I run the Spring/Hibernate web project once, the tables should automatically be created, but not overwritten the second time the application is run, correct? <br/> Further more, are any annotations required when creating the POJOs or any restrictions on the data types used, as in Sets, Arrays, Maps etc?